# How to retrieve email of users who commented on facebook comment box?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments

I am using a [Facebook comment box plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) to show comments of users for my Facebook page in my website.

Everything works fine.

But I cant get user's email who commented on my page. I want to send them thank you email.
How can I achieve it. Or is there any way to send them thank you message on facebook.

Comment: That's not possible, since email is user private data

Comment: I would be quite pissed if whenever I leave a comment on a site using the comments plugin, they would bother me with a “thank you” message …